# Show that a finite group G generated by two elements of order 2 is isomorphic to a dihedral group $D_{2n}$ for some n. (Proof Verification)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Show that a finite group G generated by two elements of order 2 is isomorphic to a dihedral group $D_{2n}$ for some n. (Proof Verification)

**Proof:**

Let G be generated by c, b, where $c^2 = b^2 = 1$. Let $a = cb$ be an element of order, say n. The element a is of finite order since G is finite. G is clearly generated by a, b since $c = cbb = ab$ is generated by a, b. Note that $a^{-1} = bc$ since $bca = bccb = 1$. Therefore $bab = bcbb = bc = a^{-1}$.

Let $\alpha$ be the rotation of $2\pi/n$ degree and $\beta$ the reflection along the line formed by $v_0$ and the origin in $D_{2n}$.

Let $f: G \to D_{2n}$ be defined by $f(a^kb^l) = \alpha^k\beta^l$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$ and $0 \leq l \leq 1$.

It is clear that $f$ is homomorphic and injective.

Now, we need to prove that $f$ is surjective. It is sufficient to show that f is surjective by showing that G has $2n$ elements since $f$ is injective.

The group G contains 2 subgroups $H_1 = <a>$ and $H_2 = <b>$ of order n and 2, respectively. If we can show that $H_1 \cap H_2 = 1$, then G must contain $2n$ elements. Clearly $b \notin H_1$ . If $a^i = b$, for $1 \leq i \leq n - 1$  then $a^{i-1} = a^ibc = bbc = c$, which is a contradiction to the fact that a is of order n. We also know that $a \neq b$, else c will be the identity, which is a contradiction. This implies that $a^i \notin H_2$

Hence, the result.

Comment: You want the homomorphism to go in the opposite direction. It's not clear that we can define it with $G$ as the domain a priori because $G$ may have other relations we don't know about. The dihedral group is the most general group with the given relations.

Comment: what do you mean? I don't quite understand

Comment: You have defined $f$. How do you know that it is a homomorphism?

Comment: okay. I think it is homomorphic but I don't really know how to show it. G defined here and dihedral groups seem to have all the same structure. G has an element of order n and element of order 2 and bab = a^-1, which is the same structure as dihedral group.

Comment: Small correction:  I think that you want your rotation to be through an angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.

Comment: @SammyBlack yup thanks. Do you have any idea how to show the isomorphism? Is my solution ok?

Answer (score 3):

We write $G=\langle s,t\rangle$, where we have renamed the two generators as $s$, $t$.

Note that $G=\langle st, t\rangle$ since $(st)t=s$. Since $G$ is finite, $st$ has a finite order, say $m$, so that $(st)^m=1_G$. We also have $[(st)t]^2=s^2=1$.

We claim that there are no other relations, other than $(st)^m=t^2=[(st)t]^2=1$.

Suppose to the contrary $sts=1$. Then $sstss=ss$, i.e.\ $t=1$, a contradiction. Similarly if $ststs=1$, $tsststsst=tsst$ implies $s=1$, a contradiction. Inductively, $(st)^ks\neq 1$ and $(ts)^kt\neq 1$ for any $k\geq 1$.

Thus $$G\cong D_{2m}=\langle a,b|a^m=b^2=(ab)^2=1\rangle.$$